# IF condintional calls js function even when it fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, label

```
var countChecked = function() {
    return $( "input:checked" ).length;
};

$( "div#signup label" ).click( function() {
    var count = countChecked();
    if ( count < 6 ) {
        $( "div#signup label" ).checkmate();
        alert( count );
    }
} );
```

When the IF conditional fails, alert() isnt called, but .checkmate() is still called.

Comment: Hard to believe. If it's really called, it must be from somewhere else.

Comment: `$( "div#signup label" ).checkmate();` only needs to be called 1 time to initialize the jquery plugin.  The alert will only be called if `count < 6` so will the initialization code but if it was called before it will still be initialized.

Comment: prove it. http://jsfiddle.net/rE3dd/ your code works as-is, it doesn't do what you say it does.

Comment: Shenanigans. Add `console.log()` calls to output `count`, and then just inside the `if` block and after the `checkmate()` call to see if it's getting to those places.

Comment: @abc123: Ahhh... thank you! Are you familiar with this plug in? I want to make sure user makes at least 1 selection, but not more than 5. I am thinking I would have to pass a conditional into checkmate() and edit that code a bit. That will prevent the label from lighting up, but it's still checked regardless. Any ideas? Thanks everyone else. Rookie mistake.

Comment: please add your html to my jsFiddle in my answer below *(then click update)* and i'll make sure it all works for you.

Comment: @abc123: thanks for the help. I've decided for the time being, to do an ajx form validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### [Demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abc123/kLSZn/2)

**JS**

```
function() countChecked {
    return $("input:checked").length;
};

$(function(){
    $("div#signup label").checkmate();

    $( "div#signup label" ).click(function(e) {
        var count = countChecked();
        if ( count < 6 ) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            alert(count);
        }
    });
});
```